# python pandas table structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

Hello i am new with python 
i flip with this look and i would like to create triplets as a result. does anyone have an idea please...

```
    name       class       number   p
 0  banana     green       933     NaN
 1  banana     yellow      991    0.01
 2  banana     red         553    0.02)
```

and the results:

```
(banana,class,green),(banana, class, yellow), (banana, class, red)
(green,number,933), (green,p,NaN)
(yellow,number,911), (yellow,p,0.01)
(red,number,533), (red,p,0.02),
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? I'm trying to better understand what you are doing. Do you want to end up with tuples like you have in your example, a transposed dataframe, or maybe something else?

Comment: the goal is to build the tuplets with the generate chart with pandas. I have not tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started. This assumes you have a dataframe named df to start with.

```
l = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    t = (row['name'], 'class', row['class'])
    l.append(t)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it works for the column class I will try to adapt for the table